# XSLT Mapper plugin for Fuse ESB

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xsd, apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am doing XML transformation in FUSE ESB. For that i am writing XSD file in XML editor, that is very hectic job for long XML files. Can anybody provide any plugin link for XSL Editor in Fuse ESB, or any Eclipse plugin that i can use in Fuse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I  have used Altova MapForce in Eclipse before for complicated XSLT transformations. It is pretty good but pricey. However it is the only one I can recommend at this point.